# Unhandled content type error

Tags: jsoup, gson

Code to get Gson string:

```
String data = Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:9000/GetJson").get().data();
```

"HTML" content from host:9000/GetJson :

```
{"Backend":"{\"onlineGames\":{},\"games\":{}}"}
```

And I go this error message:

```
Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml
```

Can somebody please show me where I were wrong :(

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup doesn't support Gson / Json, only Html, Xhtml and Xml.
If you want to use jsoup you have to wrap your gson string into html. But what do you want to do? Maybe we can help you there.

Answer (score 1):

Using **ignoreContentType(true)**:

```
String data = Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:9000/GetJson").get().ignoreContentType(true).data(
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).get();
```